# Cartopy installation on Heroku server failed. No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, heroku

I have run into an issue when I was trying to deploy an app on Heroku.

I added all the dependencies in requirements.txt file, and pushed the depository to Heroku master. All the other packages seemed to be installed successfully, except for Cartopy. It kept showing an error saying that no module named 'numpy'.

I've tried many different versions of numpy, manually added all the dependences of Cartopy, and switched between different versions of Python. I could also see numpy is successfully downloaded couple of lines above the error.

[image]

[image]

[Procfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92uRn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using docker + conda install.
Conda is a lot better at dealing with dependencies compared to pip.

Comment: I have the exact same problem deploying an pyviz panel app. Is there an example on how to use docker with jupyter notebooks and heroku?